# How to write Outer Join using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am using the below Inner Join to  retrive the Data between the two tables, but all data is not getting populated. I tried implementing Outer join by connecting using  CCY1== CCY1 and PCODE == PCODE, but no luck.

[image]

```
    var q = from g1 in TableCCY1.AsEnumerable()
            join g2 in TableCCY2.AsEnumerable()
            on g1.Field<string>("CCY1") equals g2.Field<string>("CCY1") 
            where  g1.Field<string>("PCODE") == g2.Field<string>("PCODE")
                   select new
                     {
                             g1currency = g1.Field<string>("CCY1"),
                             g2currency = g2.Field<string>("CCY1"),
                             g1code = g1.Field<string>("PCODE"),
                             g2code = g2.Field<string>("PCODE"),
                             g1Amt1 = g1.Field<string>("AMT1"),
                             g2Amt2 = g2.Field<string>("AMT2")
                     };
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have your tables a primary key? Can you explain in more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: Combination of both CCY1 and PCODE is the primary key.I want to join both the tables and get the SUM of AMT1 and AMT2. The yellow highlighted rows are the macthing one. So the output has the Sum of (AMT1 + AMT2)

Comment: OK, then what about GBP/D from CCY2 table?

Comment: CCY1= GBP PCode = D, not macthing with TableCCy1 so, no sum required.

Comment: @Ullan Then why is `KRY` in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to union/concat the two tables into one and then just group on those two columns.  You're not logically joining the two tables.  That actually makes it much easier.

```
var q = from row in TableCCY1.AsEnumerable().Concat(TableCCY2.AsEnumerable())
        group row by new
        {
            CCY1 = row.Field<string>("CCY1"),
            PCode = row.Field<string>("PCODE")
        } into matches
        select new
        {
            CCY1 = matches.Key.CCY1,
            PCODE = matches.Key.PCode,
            Sum = matches.Sum(match => match.Field<decimal?>("AMT2")),
        };
```

Comment: Nice catch, he needs concatenation indeed

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I wrote an answer similar to yours at first as well, but then it didn't match up with the expected output upon further inspection.

Comment: @Servy, thank you, I should be more specific while posting my questions.. Let me test your code now

Answer (score 2):

For left join you can use this approuch: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

The code should be:

```
var q = from g1 in TableCCY1
            join g2 in TableCCY2 on g1.CCY1 equals g2.CCY1 && g1.PCODE equals g2.PCODE into TableCCY3
from g3 in TableCCY3.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new
                     {
                             g1currency = g1.CCY1,
                             g2currency = (g3 == null ? String.Empty : g3.CCY1),
                             g1code = g1.PCODE,
                             g2code = (g3 == null ? String.Empty : g3.PCODE),
                             g1Amt1 = g1.AMT1,
                             g2Amt2 = (g3 == null ? 0 : g3.AMT2)
                     };
```